# Spring MVC - how to pass data from filter to controller

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I use **Spring MVC** in my web application. For every request I'd like to *prepare the environment*, for example load some data from the datastore and save it so every controller could access that information. I assume that's what filters are for (among other things). I can attach an information to the `request` variable in a filter, but how do I access it from the controller? Or is there a generally better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem at the moment is how to get the data set in request inside your filter( already done by you) and then accessing it inside the hamdlerMapping method of your controller( you want to achieve).

I agree with both the previous answers but if you have decided to do it this way only then I think you should follow my answer.

In the handler method you have mapped your request to in your controller you can have a parameter in method signature for `HttpServletRequest request` and it will contain the request parameter you have set in your filter. And you can get that from this request object in your controller.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why this is a good thing to do, filter or no.

If you truly have read-only data that every controller needs, I think a caching solution that is loaded on startup is a better idea.  I wouldn't do that with a filter, and I wouldn't burden every single request with such a thing.  Once it's done, why keep repeating the action?

Answer (score 0):

@duffymo is right, but if you really want to do that I suggest you to use interceptor
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

Comment: A filter is nothing more than an HTTP-specific interceptor.  My comments about not burdening every request with such a thing still stands.

Comment: Thanks. But the question is still not fully answered... how do I pass any data from an interceptor to the controller? Let's take the example used in the Spring documentation with checking opening hours. What if I wanted to use the current hour value in every handler? Yes I could count it againg, but then I would be doing the same thing twice in every request and I also would have to put a redundant line of code to every handler. I know it's not a very good example but hopefuly you get my point now.

Comment: you can for example use request.setAttribute(arg0, arg1); them you cam retrieve that date in the controller, or maybe in a session